# Wpf Multiple GridSplitter row is Growing out of the window size

Tags: c#, wpf, gridsplitter

I have 10 rows, and a button between each row,and in the rows between each button a DockPanel

The function of the button is to fully collapse or make visible the DockPanel inside the next row to collapse or make it visible again 
(by visibility.collapse and visible)

The problems i am experiencing is that after returning the DockPanel to visible state the row won't grow back again, so i have to restore its height by storing its value.

this leads me to a problem, once the height of the row is restored, the rest of the rows won't fit the window size anymore, and they can grow out of the window size,

is there a workaround to solve this issue

WPF :

```
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20" Name="rowmenu"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="0"  Name="rowfirst" MinHeight="0"   MaxHeight="0"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="20" MinHeight="20" MaxHeight="20"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="81*"  Name="rowchapter" MinHeight="20"   ></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="25" MinHeight="25" MaxHeight="25"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="81*"  Name="rowSongs"   MinHeight="20"   ></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="25" MinHeight="25" MaxHeight="25"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="81*"   Name="rowImages"   MinHeight="20"      ></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="25" MinHeight="25" MaxHeight="25" />
        <RowDefinition Height="81*"  Name="rowEfects"  MinHeight="20" ></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" MinHeight="1" Name="lastrow"  />

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="417*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

 <Button 
        Name="HeaderChapters" 
        Content="Chapters"  
        Margin="5,0,0,0" 
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
        Grid.Column="1" 
        Grid.Row="2" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top"  
        BorderBrush="CornflowerBlue" 
        BorderThickness="1" 
        Click="Button_Click"/>

    <DockPanel Name="chaptersdock" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Margin="5,0,0,0"  >
            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
            <ItemsControl  Name="ChaptersControl" BorderBrush="CornflowerBlue" BorderThickness="3" >

            </ItemsControl>
            </ScrollViewer>
    </DockPanel>

    <Button Name="HeaderSongs" 
            Content="songs"  
            Margin="5,5,0,0" 
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
            Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top"  
            BorderBrush="GreenYellow"  
            BorderThickness="1" 
            Click="Button_Click"/>

    <DockPanel Name="songsdoc" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Margin="5,0,0,0"  >
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
            <ItemsControl  Name="songsControl" BorderBrush="GreenYellow" BorderThickness="3" >

            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </DockPanel>

    <Button Name="HeaderImages" Content="Images"  
            Margin="5,5,0,0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
            Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6" VerticalAlignment="Top"  BorderBrush="Salmon"  BorderThickness="1" Click="Button_Click"/>

    <DockPanel Name="Imagesdoc" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="7" Margin="5,0,0,0"  >
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
            <ItemsControl  Name="ImagesControl" BorderBrush="Salmon" BorderThickness="3" >

            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </DockPanel>

    <Button Name="HeaderEfects" Content="Efects"  Margin="5,5,0,0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="8" VerticalAlignment="Top"  BorderBrush="Purple"  BorderThickness="1" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <DockPanel Name="Efectsdoc" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="9" Margin="5,0,0,0"  >
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
            <ItemsControl  Name="EfectsControl" BorderBrush="Purple" BorderThickness="3" >

            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </DockPanel>

    <GridSplitter  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  Width="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.RowSpan="13" />
    <GridSplitter Name="GridSplitterChapters" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.RowSpan="1" DragStarted="GridSplitterImages_DragStarted" />
    <GridSplitter Name="GridSplitterSongs" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.RowSpan="1" DragStarted="GridSplitterImages_DragStarted"  />
    <GridSplitter Name="GridSplitterImages" Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.RowSpan="1" DragStarted="GridSplitterImages_DragStarted" />
```

CS:

```
private void showhidedoc(string ControlName)
{
        DockPanel changedock = getdock(ControlName); //get the dockpanel to shrink
        RowDefinition changerow = getgrid(ControlName); //get the row to shrink
        GridSplitter changeGridSplitter = getGridsplitter(ControlName); //get the gridsplitter to disable
        changerow.Height = GridLength.Auto;

        if (changedock.Visibility == System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed) //to restore the row
        {

            changerow.MinHeight = 30; //it won't restore if it doesn't have a minwidth
            changedock.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            changeGridSplitter.IsEnabled = true; //reenable the gridsplitter
        }
        else
        {
            changerow.MinHeight = 0; //for full collapse
        //    Setrowheight(ControlName); //rowheight is stored before collapsing
            changedock.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
            changeGridSplitter.IsEnabled = false; //disable the gridsplitter
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your question is confusing ? Where is GridSplitter here ?

Comment: Sorry, there's a gridsplitter in the rowdefinitions with docpanels   

i'll share the code